# How to remove hours, minutes, and seconds from a Unix timestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, time

Without having to convert it to `datetime`, how can I get the date from a Unix timestamps? In other words, I would like to remove hours, minutes and seconds from the time stamp and get the numbers that represent the date only.

Comment: I think converting to a datetime is the best way to do this ..

Comment: unless handling a million and one special cases is your idea of fun !

Comment: I think your question isn't good idea.

Comment: Do you mean you want the unix timestamp which represents [original year] [original month] [original day] 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds? Because there is no Unix timestamp which represents only a date.

Answer (score 3):

I know you asked "without having to convert to `datetime`", but I really think this is the best method.

```
>>> t
1430103943.581003
>>> datetime.date(datetime.fromtimestamp(t)).strftime("%s")
'1430056800'
```

To do it manually will require knowing about all the special cases, leap years, leap seconds etc.  It's impractical and all the heavy lifting has already been done for you by `datetime`, so why bother?

Answer (score 1):

If running the script in a UNIX like OS, you can use the `date` command -

```
>>>import subprocess
>>>process=subprocess.Popen(['date','-d','@1430106933', '+%Y%m%d'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>>out,err = process.communicate()
>>>print out
20150426
```